# Structure Schema.org in JSON-LD format for multi branch multi departments

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm pretty sure this is purely a syntax issue, but I'm trying to setup some Schema.org in JSON-LD format for a customer that has 2 branches and each branch has 2 main departments.

The problem I'm hitting is the opening hours for each department. This is my code:

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@graph": [{
      "@id": "http://example.com",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Group Name",
      "url": "http://example.com",
      "logo": "http://example.com/images/logo.png",
      "image": "http://example.com/images/logo.png",
      "description": "Some information about the customer",
      "currenciesAccepted": "GBP",
      "sameAs": ["https://www.facebook.com/[customers facebook page/"]
    },
    {
      "@type": "AutoDealer",
      "parentOrganization": {
        "name": "Group Name"
      },
      "name": "Banch 1",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "street",
        "addressLocality": "locality",
        "addressRegion": "region",
        "postalCode": "post code",
        "telephone": "phone number"
      },
      "department": [{
          "name": "Sales Department",
          "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 9:00 - 19:00", "Sa 9:00 - 17:00"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Service Department",
          "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 7:30 - 18:00", "Sa 9:00 - 12:00"]
        }
      ],
      "hasmap": "google map url"
    },
    {
      "@type": "AutoDealer",
      "parentOrganization": {
        "name": "Group Name"
      },
      "name": "Branch 2",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "street",
        "addressLocality": "locality",
        "addressRegion": "region",
        "postalCode": "post code",
        "telephone": "phone number"
      },
      "department": [{
          "name": "Sales Department",
          "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 9:00 - 19:00", "Sa 9:00 - 17:00"]
        },
        {
          "name": "Service Department",
          "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 7:30 - 18:00", "Sa 9:00 - 12:00"]
        }
      ],
      "hasmap": "Google map url"
    }
  ]
}
```

And when I test it on Google's structured data testing tool, I get the error:

> The property `openingHours` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `Organization`.

Comment: This is way late, but LocalBusiness markup has a field for "branchCode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours) property can be used for `CivicStructure` and `LocalBusiness` types.

You don’t specify the type of the node you are providing this property for:

```json
{
  "name": "Sales Department",
  "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 9:00 - 19:00", "Sa 9:00 - 17:00"]
},
```

Google’s testing tool seems to assume that this node is of the type `Organization`, as it’s the value expected by the [`department`](http://schema.org/department) property. Because `openingHours` can’t be used on `Organization` (but on its child type `LocalBusiness`), Google gives this error.

So to fix this, add the intended type, e.g. something like:

```json
{
  "@type": "AutoDealer",
  "name": "Sales Department",
  "openingHours": ["Mo-Fr 9:00 - 19:00", "Sa 9:00 - 17:00"]
},
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for your help. Makes sense now.

Comment: @Strontium_99: You’re welcome. By the way, instead of using `@graph` and making the relation from the child organizations to their parent only implicitly via the `name` attribute, you could consider providing only the `Organization` as top-level item, and use its [`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization) property to make the connection to the two `AutoDealer` items. If that’s not possible for some reason, then you could use `@id` to give each node an identifier and use it to convey that you are talking abou the same organizations.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I'd kind of cobbled my together from a post on the internet, hence the superfluous @graph. But your suggestion feels loads more logical. Thanks Unor. You are a star.